# jQuery Isotope queue shuffle/randomize animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I would like to set the [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) shuffle method to to perform an animated shuffle of the loaded DOM elements every 30 seconds that someone is on the page with the plugin loaded.

I have had success tying the animation to a `.hover()` event, but I cannot seem to get it to fire when I use `setInterval()` or `.queue()`.  I want the animation to fire regardless of user interaction/input.

```
var iso_shuffle = function() {
    $('#isotope').isotope('shuffle');
}

setInterval(iso_shuffle(), 2500);
```

Why does the previous code not trigger the randomization, yet this does:

```
$('#isotope').hover(function() {
    iso_shuffle()
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iso_shuffle()` calls the function immediately.  The function returns nothing.  So your `setInterval` is actually doing the equivalent of:

```
setInterval(undefined, 2500);
```

You want to use the function name as the callback for `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(iso_shuffle, 2500);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the function itself, not its return value:

```
setInterval(iso_shuffle, 2500);
```