# jQuery Isotope timed shuffle

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

My question is essentially the same as [jQuery Isotope queue shuffle/randomize animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043879/jquery-isotope-queue-shuffle-randomize-animation)
...i'm trying to get my isotope filtered content to randomly rearrange at set intervals using setInterval.

The complete isotope code is as follows. At the end I am referencing the shuffle button to make the shuffle occur on hover. 
I would like the shuffle to just start and play regardless of user interaction. How can I adjust this to achieve a timed shuffle?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 // init Isotope
 var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
 itemSelector: '.element-item',
 layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
// show if number is greater than 50
numberGreaterThan50: function() {
var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
},
// show if name ends with -ium
ium: function() {
var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
return name.match( /ium$/ );
}
};
// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
// use filterFn if matches value
filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
$grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
$buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
$buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
$( this ).addClass('is-checked');
});
});

//shuffle on hover
$('.shuffle-button').hover(function() {
$grid.isotope('shuffle');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want to start interval after clicking on `.shuffle-button`? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Sorry, no I would like the interval to to begin and run regardless of user interaction

Comment: So just `setInterval(iso_shuffle, 500);` will do.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure how to apply this, i've updated my post with complete code. Would I just remove..

$('.shuffle-button').hover(function() {
    $grid.isotope('shuffle');
});

and add..
setInterval(iso_shuffle, 500);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your hover function

```
$('.shuffle-button').hover(function() {
$grid.isotope('shuffle');
});
```

with this

```
setInterval(function() {
$grid.isotope('shuffle');
 }, 2000);
```

2000 = 2 seconds, use any interval you like